# Why does "label.text = nil" act like "label.frame.height = 0", but printing the frame shows some value?

Tags: ios, swift

In storyboard I've positioned a UILabel and below I've positioned a UIView. I've pinned the UIView.Top to UILabel.Bottom.

If I set `label.text = nil` in `viewDidLoad()` the UIView.Top egde moves up for the same amount as is the `label.frame.height`.  But soon after that I print `label.frame` I can see the frame remains the same.

Why does this happen?
Am I getting the wrong frame size?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    label.text = nil
    print("label frame = \(label.frame)")
}
```

Comment: print it in view did appear

Comment: Yes, thanks @wain, printing in viewDidAppear() or viewDidLayoutSubviews() works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing the frame immediately after making a change (setting the label's text to `nil`). That's before autolayout has a chance to update the frame based on the new intrinsic content size of the label. View layouts are normally only updated once per runloop (and only if they have changed) so that you can make many changes without performing a potentially expensive re-layout after every single one.